# How to Keep the groups in a sequence

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a requirement where i have 2 datasets.One is showing calender and another is showing consolidated data for each month. In the input , i have a date calender and a text field for the number of months. Suppose user selected date as '2020-04-01' and number of month as 5, so the report will fetch the data for each month starting from April to August. The reports are grouped on month for Calnder and for the consolidated. So in my 1st page it is showing  the calender data for April month and in the next page it is showing the calender data for May then calender data for June then calender data for july, then calender data for August. Now in the next page it will show the consolidated data for APril, then consolidated data for May..till consolidated data for August. But My requirement is It should first the calender data for April month , then consolidate data for April month, then Calender data for May month then consolidated data for May month..till month of August.

I guess there is some tricks to handle these page breaks where you have mulitple groups on datasets.

Can anybody help me on this.

Regards
Subrat

Comment: I would build a sub-report that only handles a single month. In this have both tables (calendar and consolidated). Then create a master report with a simple table bound to a dataset that gives a list of required months. IN the tale insert your sub-report. If you  search SO you will fine plenty of examples, or look thru my answers on my profile page and you'll see full solutons to similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But we cannot use the subreport in my application because this SSRS report will be used as a single XML file /RDL to a different application.We are not deploying on a report server, instaead of we will used as a report viewer on a .net application that will be again used on a powerbuilder application.I am not sure how these things will work, but i cannot use a subreport on this. So please let me know if any other way is there.